# jquery get list of all elements that weren't filtered

Tags: jquery

say I have the following code:

```
var filteredList = originalList.filter(function(index) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
});
```

is there a fast way of getting all the items that were not returned in `filteredList` or would I have to do the same query but where `strpos === -1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) accepts jQuery object as a parameter as well:

```
var notFilteredList = originalList.not(filteredList);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bywJK/1/)

Comment: brilliant, that's what I was looking for! I'll mark as the answer when it lets me